# Declaring a variable in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, view

Im sorry about the mess but what I'm trying to do is create a variable for ops$u2970. I've tried some ways that I found online and they did not work. This is part of a much larger query so replacing ops$u2970 with a variable would be great especially since it will need to be changed in the future throughout the query. This is easy in Python, but alas this is sql.

```
--***Creates a VIEW of all TIS GN's with their Corridor ID, Accum Mile and XY coords
create or replace view GN_DC_LOCATE as
select distinct t.gn_id, n.tcr_rt||n.tcr_rb DC_ID,
    case when n.beg_brkm<n.end_brkm then
              round(((t.gn_km-n.beg_brkm)+n.beg_tcrkm)*.6213712,3)
         else round(((n.beg_brkm-t.gn_km)+n.beg_tcrkm)*.6213712,3)
             end as GN_DCMI,c.x_coord TIS_XCOORD, c.y_coord TIS_YCOORD
from tis.tis_gn_locate t,tis.tis_tcr_lookup n,tis.tis_gn_coords c
where t.route=n.br_id and t.gn_km>=n.beg_abskm and t.gn_km<=n.end_abskm
      and t.gn_id=c.gn_id

--***Creates a VIEW of all begin and end GN's on ops$u2087.sec_segments
--from the view GN_DC_LOCATE and adds in the records where GN=999999999999
create or replace view PVMGT_SEGS_GNs_DCMI as
select p.corridor_code_rb,
       b.gn_id,b.GN_DCMI TIS_MI,
       b.TIS_XCOORD TIS_X,b.TIS_YCOORD TIS_Y
from ops$u2970.sec_segments p, GN_DC_LOCATE b
where p.corridor_code_rb=b.DC_ID and p.beg_gn=b.gn_id
UNION
select p.corridor_code_rb,
   e.gn_id,e.GN_DCMI TIS_MI,e.TIS_XCOORD TIS_X,e.TIS_YCOORD TIS_Y
from ops$u2970.sec_segments p,GN_DC_LOCATE e
where p.corridor_code_rb=e.DC_ID and p.end_gn=e.gn_id
UNION
select p.corridor_code_rb,999999999999 GN_ID, NULL TIS_MI,NULL TIS_X,NULL   TIS_Y
from ops$u2970.sec_segments p
where p.beg_gn=999999999999 or p.end_gn=999999999999
order by 1,3
```

Comment: Which dbms? (Not ANSI SQL here...)

Comment: Well im using PL-SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to use variables in Oracle `VIEW` definitions. Variables are allowed in stored procedures, functions, triggers and packages.